# Android 8, ANDROID_ID different value for each user at signIn?

Tags: android, google-signin

Googles writes that there is a [different value of the ANDROID_ID for different users](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html).

> In O, Android ID (Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID or SSAID) has a different value for each app and each user on the device.

What does that mean if I implement [Google SignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#start_the_sign-in_flow) in an app. To be exact: The device runs under user "A@google.com". The user has the accounts "A@google.com","B@google.com","C@google.com" on his device.

When the user runs the device under ""A@google.com" and signs in the first time after app installation, he will get a popup with possible accounts. Let's assume he chooses "A@google.com". The choice will be saved in the app storage data. If he cleans the data and relaunches the app, he will get this accounts popup again and he could choose theoretically another account. 
Let's assume he chooses another account now while SignIn, "B@google.com", so his device still runs as "A@google.com", but he is logged in into the app with "B@google.com". What is the ANDROID_ID then? The ANDROID_ID from A or from B?
(I don't have an Android 8 device, so I can't check it by myself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing *account*, managed by the [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager), and *user*, managed by the [UserManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager).

> Users are different from accounts, which are managed by
>   AccountManager. Each user can have their own set of accounts.

My guess is that the `ANDROID_ID` depends on the [user serial number](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#getSerialNumberForUser(android.os.UserHandle))

From the link you provided :

> The ANDROID_ID value won't change on package uninstall/reinstall, as
>   long as the package name and signing key are the same. Apps can rely
>   on this value to maintain state across reinstalls.

In your case, if the application's data is cleared, the application id, the signature and the user are the same, so the `ANDROID_ID` should not change.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, now it is clear.
(btw: I just saw that I cannot even switch the user on my P9 lite mini Android 7, but I can switch it on my Moto G Android 5.1.)